# Como obter os N-Points FFT no R?

Tags: r

Oi, eu tenho uma questão sobre a FFT, eu estou buscando um metodo similar ao **numpy.fft.rfft**. Gostaria de saber se alguem conhece um metodo do R que calcule os *N-Points FFT*. A seguir tem os codigos com apenas fft normal.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html

Python:

```
import numpy
s = [2,4,5,6,7,12,9,8,5,0,2,5,34,1,7,26,6,3,9,1,9,36,12, 23,85,34,19,5,2,7,0,6,23,3,85,2,3,6,4,65,3,2,3,17,41,64,63,61,19,5]
numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.fft(s))
```

output:

```
array([ 859.        ,  168.68052632,  233.59258118,  119.29998998,
        261.87777496,  291.21753814,  128.36292786,  217.8378272 ,
        134.5839184 ,  176.3348246 ,  137.5572311 ,  187.26724562,
         54.49667655,  108.90964419,   59.57985882,  104.05453129,
        148.33968185,   99.25844937,   95.07400386,  193.03233757,
        208.02646027,  142.81875361,   78.02947137,  121.82303446,
         99.68797071,   55.        ,   99.68797071,  121.82303446,
         78.02947137,  142.81875361,  208.02646027,  193.03233757,
         95.07400386,   99.25844937,  148.33968185,  104.05453129,
         59.57985882,  108.90964419,   54.49667655,  187.26724562,
        137.5572311 ,  176.3348246 ,  134.5839184 ,  217.8378272 ,
        128.36292786,  291.21753814,  261.87777496,  119.29998998,
        233.59258118,  168.68052632])
```

R:

```
s = c(2,4,5,6,7,12,9,8,5,0,2,5,34,1,7,26,6,3,9,1,9,36,12, 23,85,34,19,5,2,7,0,6,23,3,85,2,3,6,4,65,3,2,3,17,41,64,63,61,19,5)
abs(fft(s))
```

output:

```
859 168.680526321364 233.592581181804 119.29998998253 261.877774963774 291.217538135653 128.362927855927 217.83782719649 134.583918396054 176.334824604301 137.557231102276 187.267245619583 54.4966765477317 108.909644186516 59.579858824858 104.054531291096 148.339681846157 99.2584493737003 95.0740038555544 193.032337566808 208.026460267619 142.818753605427 78.029471367604 121.823034461609 99.6879707119806 55 99.6879707119805 121.823034461609 78.029471367604 142.818753605427 208.026460267619 193.032337566808 95.0740038555545 99.2584493737003 148.339681846157 104.054531291096 59.579858824858 108.909644186516 54.4966765477317 187.267245619583 137.557231102276 176.334824604301 134.583918396054 217.83782719649 128.362927855927 291.217538135653 261.877774963774 119.29998998253 233.592581181804 168.680526321365
```

Comment: Eu não entendi a dúvida. Me parece que os resultados de `numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.fft(s))` e `abs(fft(s))` são idênticos (exceto por alguns erros de arredondamento). Ambos tem comprimento igual a 50 e a soma dos elementos não difere até a 12a. casa decimal.

Comment: @MarcusNunes `any(abs(numpy - R) > .Machine$double.eps^0.5)` dá `[1] FALSE`. (`numpy` e `R` são os vetores acima.)

Comment: Rodei aqui o comando `max(abs(numpy - R))` e o resultado foi 4.858045e-09. Ou seja, a diferença máxima para uma das posições (no caso, a 15a.) está na nona casa decimal. Eu não me preocuparia com isso. A diferença é irrisória. Além disso, tanto `R` quanto `python` são famosos por erros de arredondamento (por exemplo, rode `(2-1.8) == .2` no `R` e veja que ele reporta `FALSE`). Uma outra maneira de testar e realmente ter certeza de que os vetores são iguais, utilize `all.equal(numpy, R)` e veja que a resposta é `TRUE`, indicando que estes vetores são _aproximadamente_ iguais.

Comment: Eu estava buscando uma  função que obtesse os N-Points FFT, estava mostrando acima que o codigo funciona para obter o FFT normalmente, mas quero uma função similar ao rfft, no qual eu passo os N points. Mas eu descobri como fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui criar uma função em R similar ao **numpy.fft.rfft**. Eu vou deixar  pergunta pois essa resposta pode ser util para alguem.
Em Python a operação efetuada a seguir gera o respectivo output quando **n = 8**:

```
import numpy
s = [2,4,5,6,7,12,9,8,5,0,2,5,34,1,7,26,6,3,9,1,9,36,12, 23,85,34,19,5,2,7,0,6,23,3,85,2,3,6,4,65,3,2,3,17,41,64,63,61,19,5]
numpy.absolute(numpy.fft.rfft(s,8))
```

**Output:**

```
array([ 53.        ,  14.42203   ,   5.38516481,   3.16307613,   7.        ])
```

O trecho em R fica:

```
rfft <- function(x, n){
    mag <- abs(fft(x[1:n]))
    n <- ceiling((n + 1) / 2)
    mag[1:n]
}

s = c(2,4,5,6,7,12,9,8,5,0,2,5,34,1,7,26,6,3,9,1,9,36,12, 23,85,34,19,5,2,7,0,6,23,3,85,2,3,6,4,65,3,2,3,17,41,64,63,61,19,5)
rfft(s,8)
```

**Output:**

```
53 14.4220300015676 5.3851648071345 3.163076134696 7
```